# boost::asio emulation of poll on file descriptor

Tags: select, boost-asio

I have a 3rd party library with an interface to integrate it into a main loop / event handler.
This interface provides a filedescriptor and the main loop has to check it for different events (read/write/error/hangup) which are forwarded to the library using callbacks.
I want to integrate the library in boost::asio.
I know that I can use `posix::stream_descriptor` to use the filedescriptor in asio and I know that `null_buffers` can be used to detect the "read/write ready" state of the filedescriptor without reading from it.
What's missing is an event for error and hangup (POLLERR and POLLHUP in `poll()`)
Is there a way to get these events from asio?
I have seen such a function in glib([g-source-add-poll](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-add-poll)).

Thank you very much,

Cubi